# Output of multiple thread executions only happens once?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void func() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads; 
    int n = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         std::cout << "executing thread" << std::endl;
         threads.push_back(std::thread(func));
    }
}
```

My program prints "executing thread" once and it ends. What is the cause?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Probably your program ends before any threads actually starts. But yes, if you want an answer, provide an MCVE.

Comment: The ***current*** problem you have is the same as in the duplicate. Once you fix that you have the problem all answers here tell you about.

Comment: @UKMonkey, what does "start your threads in a function" mean?

Comment: @jameslarge look at the edit history

Answer (score 1):

After this loop completes the destructor of `std::vector<std::thread>` is invoked. [`std::thread` destructor calls `std::terminate` if the thread was neither detached nor joined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread), like in your case.

To fix that, add the following after the loop:

```
for(auto& thread : threads)
    thread.join();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you join the threads to wait for them all to complete:

```
for (auto &thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

If the program continues after this point and doesn't exit immediately, flush the output since it may be buffered:

```
std::cout << std::flush;
```

Comment: even after adding these lines of code after the loop, my for loop is executing only once. @jspcal

Comment: OP has `std::endl` which already does flush the stream

Comment: the question isnt about the `"Hello"` but about the `cout` in `main` which appears only once and that one has a `endl`

Comment: OPs comment below a different answer: "i guess you didn't get my question. the loop executes only once i.e "executing thread" is only printed once. This is the problem I am getting"

Comment: @user463035818: That's irrelevant. The point about needing to flush is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't join, it should still print "executing thread" 100 times.

Perhaps the problem is using "endl" instead of "std::endl"

Answer (score 0):

Once the loop creating the threads is done, your program continues. And it continues to leave the `main` function which causes all variables defined inside the `main` function to go out of scope and their life-time ending. This leads to the destruction of the objects, including the vector which then leads to all the thread object in the vector being destructed.

And as noted by others, the destruction of a thread object will lead to program termination if the thread is not joined or detached.

---

While the other answers tell you to join the threads (which IMO is the recommended solution here) there is another possible solution: To detach the threads.

While this will lead to the `std::terminate` function to be called and prematurely terminate your program, this will lead to *another* problem, as leaving the `main` function ends the process *and all its threads*.

If you for some reason what your threads to continue to live on after the `main` function exits, you need to detach the threads *and* exit the "main thread" using an operating-system specific function. This will leave the process running with all your created threads still chugging along.

Comment: i guess you didn't get my question. the loop executes only once i.e "executing thread" is only printed once. This is the problem I am getting.